# Is it safe to install VC++ 6.0 after Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, installation

When I built this new PC I didn't install VC++ 6.0 as I didn't think I'd ever need it again.

However, I've just discovered I need to rebuild a really old application. It doesn't compile under VS 2008 (which isn't surprising since it hasn't been touched in 7 years) and as my C++ skills are a little rusty I don't have the time to try and work out whether I can change the code or not.

The easiest solution would seems to be just to install VC++ 6.0, but I can't find any information as to whether it's a sensible thing to do or not.

Basically, will it break my VS 2008 install?

Comment: That kind of problems are the reason why you should have a separate production system.  For my applications, I have a dedicated production system that runs one version of the compiler and is never changed (no service packs, no new DLL's, no patches, nothing).  If I decide to move to a new compiler, I ask my boss for a new production system, which then runs the new compiler version and all up-to-date patches and services packs.  Then this new production system is never updated again.  Additionally you may want to virtualize really old production systems in case the hardware breaks down.

Comment: @Patrick - well if this was work related there wouldn't be a problem - I'd just put in a request for a new machine. However, it's my own personal project. I will investigate virtual machines, but lack of OS licenses might well make that a non-starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had Visual Studio 6.0, 2003, 2005, and 2008 installed on the same machine and could compile code on each one without any trouble. Granted, I did install 2008 *after* 6.0 was already installed, but I would expect the installation would not cause problems.

That said, a safer approach would be to just create a VM using Virtual PC or VMWare, if that is a viable option for you. That way you do not run the risk of messing up your system.

Comment: in the past I've always installed VC6++ first hence I know that they co-exist quite happily, but I'm just worried that there'll be some clash. Virtual Machines are bit of a non-starter at the moment - lack of access to OS licenses being the biggest problem.